# ColdFusion Client Variables are purged from database prematurely

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an application that uses client variables to track login state and the Client Variables for the application are using a database for storage.  I have the purge interval set for 1 day and we are seeing instances where a user is logged out within seconds of the last page load due to missing client variables because a client variable purge occurred just before.  We also have "Disable Global Client Variables Updates" checked.

I have a hunch the purge algorithm compares the LASTVISIT variable to the current date/time to determine which records to purge, but I can't verify this. It would explain why we are seeing this "anomoly" since my application is not updating this variable, LASTVISIT is set to the start date of when the record was created.

Could this be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Lot's of things could be the issue.  Did you read the purge algorithm?

Comment: That's my issue.  I can't find any official documentation indicating what the purge algorithm is.  I've seen some posts indicating it checks the lvisit field, but I also can't find any official documentation indicating the lvisit field doesn't get updated if the Global Variable update is turned off.